# Hive Error: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 4:28 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'status_cd'

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

I have the following query in HIVE which throwing "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 4:28 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'status_cd'" Error.

Whole query seems to be correct, I executed similar query in MYSQL also which is working fine. Only in Hive it throwing error.

Is there any limitation in HIVE which causing the problem.

Please look into below query, Any help will be appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE stg_dim_gate_package SELECT
    `16_1693_418`.`package_id` AS `6896_package_id`,
    `16_1723_432`.`status_cd` AS `7075_status_cd`,
    `16_1723_432`.`load_dt` AS `7076_load_dt`,
    `16_1723_432`.`mod_dt` AS `7077_mod_dt`,
    (
        COUNT(`16_1693_418`.`package_id`)
    ) AS `7078_package_count`
FROM
    `16_1693_418`
LEFT JOIN `16_1723_432` ON `16_1693_418`.`candidateid` > `16_1723_432`.`status_cd`
GROUP BY
    `16_1693_418`.`package_id`,
    `16_1723_432`.`status_cd`,
    `16_1723_432`.`load_dt`,
    `16_1723_432`.`mod_dt`;
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN columnA > columnB` seems to be incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive currently support only EQUIJOIN. Thus you can't use `ON tableA.col1 > tableB.col2`, but you can only do `ON tableA.col1 = tableB.col2`.

Then, to achive your goal, you have to rewrite the query, using a case statement to handle the SEMIJOIN...

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports only equi join . Any condition other than the equi join can be put in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Only `JOIN` supports:

`>` and `<`

Only `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` do support:  `EQUIJOIN`